# how to parse stdout by line

Tags: vbscript, split, newline, stdout

I am passing a set of data (multiple lines) not from file/text but from arguments (stdOut). I need to do this in VBS.

```
for each new line
{
do something
}
```

I suspect I need to make use of the `split` function? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please provide us an example how do you pass data to a script, e.g. `cscript my.vbs "arg 1" "arg 2" arg3` or  `cscript my.vbs < my.txt` or  `cscript my.vbs my.txt`?